# Solving for k in $ \log_{5} x = k \cdot \log_{10} x$

Tags: logarithms

If $ \log_{5} x = k \cdot \log_{10} x$

find the value of $k$ (rough approximation) without using calculator.

what i did is:

$ \log_{5} x = \log_{5}10 \cdot \log_{10}x$

$\therefore \:k = \log_{5}10 $

$\Rightarrow\: (1+4)^k = 10 $

$ 10 = (1+4)^k= 1+ 4k + \frac{k(k-1)}{ 2!}k^2 + \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}k^3\cdots$

but after that i could not find a way to get the value of k.

[would be appreciated if someone solves the above series for k.]

Comment: I think you meant to write, $$\therefore k=\log_510,$$ which gives you what you want immediately, namely $1+\log_52.$

Comment: yeah;
corrected

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln 5}=\frac{k\ln x}{\ln 10}\implies k=\frac{\ln 10}{\ln 5}=1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5}\approx 1.43$$ because $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5}\approx\frac37$, because $2^7\approx 5^3$.

Comment: without using calculator :)

Comment: Alternatively, $\frac{\log 2 + \log 5}{\log 5} = 1 + \frac{\log 2}{\log 5} = 1 + \log_5 2$.

Comment: @sakib Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @TravisWillse OP already had the answer. He only made an oversight.

Comment: @allawonder I'm not sure what you're referring to, though it looks like some comments have been removed in the meantime. I was only pointing out an alternative expression for the answer.